# Vector Space is a Free Module

Tags: vector-spaces, modules

[image]
Is this argument correct? They assume $B$ doesn’t span $V$. Then ${B}^{‘} = B \cup (v) $. And they say $\alpha v + \sum_{i=1}^r \alpha_ib_i$ = 0 implies that $\alpha\neq0$ otherwise every scalar becomes zero. My question here is that there is typo here isn’t it? $B^‘$ must be linearly dependent right if $\alpha\neq0$? Another question is what is the problem if all scalars are zero? That will show that $B^‘$ is linearly independent and will belong in $\mathscr F$ and that will contradict the maximality of $B$. Isn’t this argument sounding circular? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Which book is this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$v$ is by assumption (that $B$ is not a basis) **not** a linear combination of any finite subset of $B$. In particular, $v \notin \text{span}(B)$. So it's right, that $B' = B \cup \{v\}$ is linear **independent** (because if it was linear dependent, then there would be an $(\alpha,\alpha_1,...,\alpha_r) \neq 0$ and a sum $\alpha v+\sum_{i=1}^r \alpha_i b_i =0$ which would imply $v \in \text{span}(B)$ (as in the text)). Thus $B' \in \mathscr{F}$ which is a contradiction to the maximality.

Comment: How $\alpha = 0$ will imply that $ v \in span(B)$? You can’t divide by 0. $\alpha = 0$ combined with other scalars being zero will make $B^’$ linearly independent isn’t it? Here they say $\alpha \neq 0$ won’t that make $B^’$ linearly dependent?

Comment: I elaborated on it in the comment.